# Change url query string value based on configurator selections using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Super new (literally my first week) to JQ and JavaScript in general so I'll try to explain the best I can.

My goal: Change URL query string to represent the user's multiple selections in my mini configurator so I can create hidden variables in a Typeform.

Image of mini configurator: [image: configurator UI]

Example: The user selects light wood as their interior color and black as their exterior color. The URL query string would then show https://example/interiorid-exteriorid

My approach:

Populate the URL after the user has selected both interior and exterior color (logically far from the right approach but my lack of knowledge hindered my thought process). Although my method works the first time the user selects both fields, if they go back and change the interior color, the URL doesn't update unless they change the exterior color again. Feel free to check it [here](https://shift-steelblox.webflow.io/#configure)

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.options_interior-color').click(function() {
      var intId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('.options_color-code-wrap').click(function comboUi() {
      var extId = $(this).attr('id');
      const stateObj = {
        path: extId
      };

      if ($('#medium').hasClass('active')) {
        window.history.replaceState(stateObj, '', 'medium' + '-' + extId);
      }
      if ($('#light').hasClass('active')) {
        window.history.replaceState(stateObj, '', 'light' + '-' + extId);
      }
      if ($('#dark').hasClass('active')) {
        window.history.replaceState(stateObj, '', 'dark' + '-' + extId);
      }
      if ($('#black').hasClass('active')) {
        window.history.replaceState(stateObj, '', 'black' + '-' + extId);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My question: Could I make it so the URL adds the interior id on interior selection (https://example.com/interiorid) and then adds the exterior id onto that string after it's been chosen (https://example.com/interiorid-exteriorid). If either interior or exterior fields are changed, it finds and replaces the related id.

Trying to figure this out has made my brain smoother than it was to begin with. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One issue you need to resolve quickly doing it this way is how to configure server to manage those paths. If you use url query string instead you don't need any server configuration. `mysite.com/configurator.html?ext-color=brown&int-color=white`. Reading and writing these are easy using the URLSearchParams API

Comment: This is actually really helpful. I know what to research now so I can ask better questions or even better, figure it out for myself. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't quite follow what I meant about server config....just try a page reload after you do one of your current pushstates. Server will give you a 404 not found

Comment: Yeah, I see that. I don't need the URL to work though. Once the user selects their colors and clicks the order now button, Typeform will update form fields based on the URL that the user comes from. So if they select black exterior black interior, and hit the order button, the form fields exterior color and interior color will be appropriately filled out with the value black and the user won't have to answer those questions twice.

Comment: People do page refreshes all the time for  a variety of different reasons. Or if they bookmark it after they try the UI and have to do something else. The bookmark would be useless

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It's not the best UX